# How to configure cross region VPC peering on AWS with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, terraform, vpc-peering

I'm trying to create a terraform configuration to spin up multiple VPCs in different regions and create VPC peer connections between them.

This is my module for the VPC

```
# Required Variables

variable "region" {}
variable "cluster_name" {}
variable "region_name" {}
variable "nb_nodes" {}
variable "vpc_cidr" {}

# Default Variables

variable "instance_type" {
    default = "t2.nano"
}

variable "public_key_path" {
    default = "id_rsa.pub"
}

variable "private_key_path" {
    default = "id_rsa"
}

variable "ami-username" {
    default = "ubuntu"
}

variable "ami" {
    type = "map"

    default = {
        us-east-1 = "ami-0f9cf087c1f27d9b1"
        us-east-2 = "ami-0653e888ec96eab9b"
    }
}

variable "availability_zone" {
    type = "map"

    default = {
        us-east-1 = "us-east-1a"
        us-east-2 = "us-east-2a"
    }
}

provider "aws" {
    region = "${var.region}"
}

# Network Resources

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true

    tags {
        Name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.region_name}-vpc"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
    cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
    availability_zone = "${lookup(var.availability_zone, var.region)}"

    tags {
        Name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.region_name}-subnet"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
    name = "vpc_test"
    description = "Allow all"

    ingress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    egress {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

    vpc_id="${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    tags {
        Name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.region_name}-security-group"
    }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    tags {
        Name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.region_name}-gateway"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public-rt" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.gw.id}"
    }

    tags {
        Name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.region_name}-subnet-rt"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public-rt" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.public-rt.id}"
}


# Instance Resources

resource "aws_key_pair" "kp" {
    key_name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.region_name}-key"
    public_key = "${file("${var.public_key_path}")}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "node" {
    ami = "${lookup(var.ami, var.region)}"
    instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
    count = "${var.nb_nodes}"

    key_name = "${aws_key_pair.kp.id}"
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.sg.id}"]
    source_dest_check = false
    associate_public_ip_address = true

    root_block_device {
        volume_size = 20
    }

    tags {
        Name = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.region_name}-${count.index}"
    }
}

output "region" {
    value = "${var.region}"
}

output "vpc_id" {
    value = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```

and this is the module to create the peer connections

```
# Required Variables

variable "request_vpc_id" {}
variable "accept_vpc_id" {}
variable "request_region" {}
variable "accept_region" {}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

provider "aws" {
    region = "${var.request_region}"
}

resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "con" {
    peer_owner_id = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
    vpc_id        = "${var.request_vpc_id}"
    peer_vpc_id   = "${var.accept_vpc_id}"
    auto_accept   = true
}
```

If I do something like this which creates 2 VPCs in the same region it works fine

```
variable "cluster_name"{
    default = "aws-multi-region"
}

variable "nodes_per_region" {
    default = "1"
}

module "region-1" {
    source  = "./simple_region/"
    region = "us-east-1"
    cluster_name = "${var.cluster_name}"
    region_name = "east"
    vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"
    nb_nodes = "${var.nodes_per_region}"
}

module "region-2" {
    source  = "./simple_region/"
    region = "us-east-1"
    cluster_name = "${var.cluster_name}"
    region_name = "west"
    vpc_cidr = "11.1.1.0/24"
    nb_nodes = "${var.nodes_per_region}"
}

module "vpc_peer_1" {
    source  = "./vpc_peer/"
    request_region = "${module.region-1.region}"
    request_vpc_id = "${module.region-1.vpc_id}"
    accept_region = "${module.region-2.region}"
    accept_vpc_id = "${module.region-2.vpc_id}"
}
```

The problem comes if I try to create the VPCs in different regions like this

```
variable "cluster_name"{
    default = "aws-multi-region"
}

variable "nodes_per_region" {
    default = "1"
}

module "region-1" {
    source  = "./simple_region/"
    region = "us-east-1"
    cluster_name = "${var.cluster_name}"
    region_name = "east"
    vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"
    nb_nodes = "${var.nodes_per_region}"
}

module "region-2" {
    source  = "./simple_region/"
    region = "us-east-2"
    cluster_name = "${var.cluster_name}"
    region_name = "west"
    vpc_cidr = "11.1.1.0/24"
    nb_nodes = "${var.nodes_per_region}"
}

module "vpc_peer_1" {
    source  = "./vpc_peer/"
    request_region = "${module.region-1.region}"
    request_vpc_id = "${module.region-1.vpc_id}"
    accept_region = "${module.region-2.region}"
    accept_vpc_id = "${module.region-2.vpc_id}"
}
```

I get an error

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.vpc_peer_1.aws_vpc_peering_connection.con: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_vpc_peering_connection.con: Error waiting for VPC Peering Connection to become available: Error waiting for VPC Peering Connection (pcx-0d423f938490fde63) to become available: Failed due to incorrect VPC-ID, Account ID, or overlapping CIDR range

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

I've tried manually creating the vpc connections in the aws ui and that works fine so I'm wondering if this is a terraform bug or if I need to do something with the regions in the vpc_peer module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this is the answer

```
# Required Variables

variable "request_vpc_id" {}
variable "accept_vpc_id" {}
variable "request_region" {}
variable "accept_region" {}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

provider "aws" {
    region = "${var.request_region}"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "peer"
  region = "${var.accept_region}"
}

# Requester's side of the connection.
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "peer" {
  vpc_id        = "${var.request_vpc_id}"
  peer_vpc_id   = "${var.accept_vpc_id}"
  peer_owner_id = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
  peer_region   = "${var.accept_region}"
  auto_accept   = false

  tags = {
    Side = "Requester"
  }
}

# Accepter's side of the connection.
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" "peer" {
  provider                  = "aws.peer"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.peer.id}"
  auto_accept               = true

  tags = {
    Side = "Accepter"
  }
}
```

Comment: Great that you've figured it out. If it works as expected accept your answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow.